# FORTRAN link files issue (Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1))

Tags: hyperlink, fortran

I've a big model code written in multiple fortran subroutines (.F &.F90 formats). There are few .F files which uses just one line of code like:

```
link ../../dir1/module1.F
```

During compilation of code, it generates an error saying:

```
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

I am not sure what's wrong there. I've asked the person who created this and she said there might be some setting issue or something. I don't use FORTRAN that much so I am confused. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the entire error, e.g. the line triggering the error so we can see what (1) is?  My guess is the .F files are free form and the compiler is assuming fixed form given the file extension.

Comment: So that file only contains one line of code. Let's say the name of the file is module2.F and it is supposed to create a symbolic link for module1.F in dir1. But that's not working.